# Hide and show a view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have small view with a UITextField in it. I want to make the view hidden by default. when a button clicked it should show the view and the elements in main view below this sub view must be scrolled down. Any idea? I'm attaching the screenshots[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `UITextView` as `hidden` from InterfaceBuilder (you can set it from code too).

After this attach this action handler to the `UIButton`.

```
- (IBAction)showTextBar
{
    [textView setHidden:False];
    return;
}
```

This will show the textBar. If you want to show some other elements then you can add them in this method. Also you can make this method like a toggle. click once to show the elements, click again to hide them.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the action u can also use

```
textView.hidden = NO;
```

As for the scrolling use a UIScrollView something like

```
[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,_textView.center.y+168) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

//Alternate between hide and show when button is clicked

```
    -(IBAction)showTextBar

     {

       if(textview.hidden)
        {
            [textView setHidden:False];
        }
        else
        {
            [textView setHidden:True];
        }

    }
```